# GameBoy ISA (Writing an Emulator)

Tags: assembly, emulation, cpu-registers, z80, gameboy

I am working on a GameBoy emulator in C. Right now I am working on the CPU.c file and I am a little confused on some instructions that I see listed here:

http://realboyemulator.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/gbcpuman.pdf

If you refer to page 66 of the above PDF, and look at the instruction corresponding with Opcode 0x7E -- LD,R1,R2 , I am curious about this isntruction..

The GB has eight 8 bit registers, A,B,C,D,E,F,H,L. 16 Bit registers can be made by concatenating two: AF,BC,DE,HL.

I am confused about Opcode 0x7E because it looks like it is attempting to store a 16 bit value (HL) into an 8-bit register (A).

LD,A,(HL)

Am I misinterpreting this document? Can someone explain why an instruction like this would exist? Could it not just be replaced by LD,A,L?

Comment: Do you know the value of HL?
I'm a bit rusty at assembly but wouldn't it store the upper half or lower half depending on big or little endians?

Comment: HL is a 16 bit value comprised made up from 8 bit registers H and L where H contains the upper 8 bits and L the lower

Comment: I assume it is the address HL as you mentioned, then you read the memory location pointed to by HL, that 8 bit value read at that address then goes into register A.  That is probably what the (parenthesis) are there for, to indicate a level of indirection.

Comment: After looking at some other people source on line, you are absolutely correct, if you make it an answer I will select it! Thank you!

Comment: I assume you know the GB is a z80 instruction set with some modifications.  Looking at the referecnes they use parenthesis for that indirect addressing mode. (whatever) means whatever is the address and you read from or write the data to that address. without the parens the register itself is the source or destination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address is 16 bit but it points into 1 byte (8 bit) which it puts into register A, (register D in the below example).

```
LD D, (HL)
```

This instruction loads D with the byte located at the address in register pair HL.

Found this at http://gameboy.mongenel.com/dmg/lesson1.html

Here are all the lessons
http://gameboy.mongenel.com/asmschool.html

Comment: General note, in assembly languages parens usually mean loading from memory. Some CISC ISAs even have instructions that will load twice, denoted like `X(Y(RA))` or `X(Y[RA])`.

Comment: Z80 specific observation about Potatoswatter's note: the instruction `JP (HL)` breaks the normal rule by loading the value of `HL` directly into the program counter without reading anything from RAM. So if it were consistent with the immediate `JP 1234h` instructions it would have no brackets. Watch for that, when you get to it, if that instruction is implemented on the GB's not-quite-a-z80.

Comment: @Tommy: is that opcode E9? In the pan/koopa/nocash docs (http://nocash.emubase.de/pandocs.htm#cpuinstructionset) it's written as `JP HL`

Comment: @ninjalj yes, E9. If you check out primary sources like the original Zilog data sheet http://www.z80.info/zip/z80.pdf you'll see it stated as `JP (HL)` (page 18). I guess secondary sources have seen fit to correct that.